# Jboss redeploy don't update jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, jboss-eap-6

I have a strange problem with my spring application.  When I re-deploy it on JBoss EAP 6.2. sometimes Jboss not update really my jsp and I recive the html generated with the previus version.This not appened for static content. For resolve this problem I have to delete the content of temp folder into standalone. Restat Jboss don't resolve the problem.

**Solution :**

Add this to standalone.xml

```
<extensions>
.........
</extensions>

<system-properties>
    <property name="org.jboss.as.web.deployment.DELETE_WORK_DIR_ONCONTEXTDESTROY" value="true"/>
</system-properties>

<management>
...........
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your info, in EAP 6.1.0 and later, you can set the following system property `org.jboss.as.web.deployment.DELETE_WORK_DIR_ONCONTEXTDESTROY` to `true` in order to delete the JSP cache each time on context destroy.
Unfortunately, the default for this property is false. In order to ensure that JSP sources are recompiled, you use this property to remove .java and .class files.